# Estado HTTP 500 No se puede compilar la clase para JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

Buenas tardes tengo mi dynamic web project en eclipse, hice un formulario donde envió información que sera utilizada en **recibir.jsp** pero me muestra este error con las librerías, si quito las librerías y recibo los datos de un jsp a otro no me da problemas, el programa sirve bien corriéndolo en una proyecto java en eclipse, ya agregue el jar de las librerías al build path, pero la verdad ya no se me ocurre nada más para que funciones, agradezco cualquier ayuda.

**Error**

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: No se puede compilar la clase para
>   JSP:
>
> Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: [15] en el fichero java
>   generado:
>   [C:\Users\hgomez\Proyectos.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\ZIP\org\apache\jsp\recibir_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile resolves
>   to a package
>
> Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: [16] en el fichero java
>   generado:
>   [C:\Users\hgomez\Proyectos.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\ZIP\org\apache\jsp\recibir_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException
>   resolves to a package
>
> Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: [17] en el fichero java
>   generado:
>   [C:\Users\hgomez\Proyectos.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\ZIP\org\apache\jsp\recibir_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. net.lingala.zip4j.model.ZipParameters
>   resolves to a package
>
> Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: [18] en el fichero java
>   generado:
>   [C:\Users\hgomez\Proyectos.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\ZIP\org\apache\jsp\recibir_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. net.lingala.zip4j.util.Zip4jConstants
>   resolves to a package
>
> Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 28 en el archivo jsp:
>   /recibir.jsp ZipFile cannot be resolved to a type 25:      26: try { 27: 
>   28:   ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(ruta + entrada + ".zip");
>   29:     ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters(); 30:
>   parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE); 31:
>   parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
>
> Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 28 en el archivo jsp:
>   /recibir.jsp ZipFile cannot be resolved to a type 25:      26: try { 27: 
>   28:   ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(ruta + entrada + ".zip");
>   29:     ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters(); 30:
>   parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE); 31:
>   parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
>
> Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 29 en el archivo jsp:
>   /recibir.jsp ZipParameters cannot be resolved to a type 26: try { 27: 
>   28:   ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(ruta + entrada + ".zip");
>   29:     ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters(); 30:
>   parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE); 31:
>   parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
>   32:
>
> Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 29 en el archivo jsp:
>   /recibir.jsp ZipParameters cannot be resolved to a type 26: try { 27: 
>   28:   ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(ruta + entrada + ".zip");
>   29:     ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters(); 30:
>   parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE); 31:
>   parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
>   32:
>
> Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 30 en el archivo jsp:
>   /recibir.jsp Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE cannot be resolved to a type
>   27:     28:   ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(ruta + entrada + ".zip");
>   29:     ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters(); 30:
>   parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE); 31:
>   parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
>   32:             33:     zipFile.addFolder(ruta + entrada, parameters);
>
> Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 31 en el archivo jsp:
>   /recibir.jsp Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL cannot be resolved to
>   a type 28:    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(ruta + entrada + ".zip");
>   29:     ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters(); 30:
>   parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE); 31:
>   parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);
>   32:             33:     zipFile.addFolder(ruta + entrada, parameters);
>   34: }
>
> Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 36 en el archivo jsp:
>   /recibir.jsp ZipException cannot be resolved to a type 33:
>   zipFile.addFolder(ruta + entrada, parameters); 34: }  35:  36: catch
>   (ZipException e) { 37:    38:      39: }
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:490)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)**

**Inicio.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>ZIP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Comprimir en zip </h1>

<form action="recibir.jsp" method="GET">
Carpeta:
<input type="text" name="Carpeta"/>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**recibir.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 
<%@ page import="net.lingala.zip4j.*" %>
<%@page import= "net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile" %> 
<%@ page import= "net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException" %>
<%@ page import= "net.lingala.zip4j.model.ZipParameters" %> 
<%@ page import="net.lingala.zip4j.util.Zip4jConstants" %>
<%@ page import= "java.io.File" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Recibir</title>
</head>
<body>


<% 
String entrada=request.getParameter("Carpeta");
String ruta = "C:/ZIP/";

out.println("Carpeta a comprimir:");
out.println(ruta + entrada +".zip");


try {

    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(ruta + entrada + ".zip");               
    ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
        parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
        parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);

    zipFile.addFolder(ruta + entrada, parameters);
} 

catch (ZipException e) {


}

%>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error es un error genérico en los JSPs. Lo más seguro es que te falte el jar que contiene la clase que estás intentando importar o no lo estás definiendo en tu classpath que normalmente es dentro del directorio

```
WEB-INF/lib
```